# Modifying parameter in existing text file with Python

Tags: python

I have a text file (example.txt) which looks like this:

```
sn = 50
fs=60
bw=10
temperature=20
ch=10

rx_b_phase = 204c7a76
rx_b_gain  = 113
tx_b_phase = 01ff03e1
tx_b_gain  = 105

#sample_gain
sample_gain_hi = 7dc
sample_gain_mid = 7d0
sample_gain_low = 7c9

psl = 44
pin = -1728

#tmpr_reg   temperature,pa_reg,wfp_reg
tmpr_reg = 1,d4,1b
tmpr_reg = 6,d3,1b
tmpr_reg = 12,d2,1b
tmpr_reg = 17,d1,1b
```

I need to modify/update the following parameters: `rx_b_phase`, `sample_gain_hi` without change anything else. How would I do this with Python?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fileinput` module:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('example.txt', inplace = True):
    if line.startswith('rx_b_phase'):
        #if line starts with rx_b_phase then do something here
        print "rx_b_phase = foo"
    elif line.startswith('sample_gain_hi'):
        #if line starts with sample_gain_hi then do something here
        print "sample_gain_hi = bar"
    else:
        print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use mmap to do this ( one caveat is that your updated lines need the same length as the old ones -- so you might need to pad with spaces )

```
>>> import mmap
>>> f = open("config.conf", "r+b")
>>> mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
>>> mm.find("sample_gain_hi")
134
>>> new_line = "sample_gain_hi = 999"
>>> mm[134:134+len(new_line)] = new_line
>>> mm.close()
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: this works fine, but you need to ensure the new_line with exact number of whitespaces, else new data will be with some chunks of old data