# What is the best way to modify a text file in-place?

Tags: python, file, in-place

I have a text file, (let's call it 'Potatoes.txt') containing the following info:

```
Town 1,300,
Town 2,205,
Town 3,600,
Town 4,910,
Town 5,360,
```

What I want to do is decrease the number for certain towns, and modify the text file accordingly.
I did a little research and it appears you can't modify text files, and I need the text file to have the same name, just have different values inside it, so I'm currently doing this instead:

```
f = open("ModifiedPotatoes.txt","w")
f.close()

with open("Potatoes.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
       info = line.split(",")
       if "Town 2" or "Town 4" in line:
           info[1] -= 20
       with open("ModifiedPotatoes.txt","a"):
           infoStr = "\n" + ",".join(str(x) for x in info)
           file.write(infoStr)

f = open("Potatoes.txt","w")
f.close()

with open("ModifedPotatoes.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        with open("Potatoes.txt","a") as potatoesFile:
            potatoesFile.write(line)
```

So basically I'm just overwriting the old file to a blank one, then copying the value from the modified/temporary file. Is there a better way to do this I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Modifying text file after certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134163/python-modifying-text-file-after-certain-character) and [Modifying parameter in existing text file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17067573/62576) and many others (search here for *python modify text file*).

Comment: Does the order of the towns in the file matter? How large is the file (can we fit it all into memory)?

Comment: Don't forget to use `w` instead of `r` in `with open("ModifedPotatoes.txt","r") as file:`

Answer (score 6):

> I did a little research and it appears you can't modify text files

There is a module that gives you the same effect as modifying text as you loop over it.  Try using the [*fileinput*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module with the *inplace* option set to *True*.

Here is a little Python3.6 code to get you started:

```
from fileinput import FileInput

with FileInput(files=['Potatoes.txt'], inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        info = line.split(",")
        if "Town 2" in line or "Town 4" in line:
            info[1] = int(info[1]) - 20
            line = ",".join(str(x) for x in info))
        print(line)
```

Comment: I also came across this module but what is the advantage of using it over the solution mentioned by jeff-k

Comment: @himanshu219 One advantage is that the process is automated.  Another advantage is that fileinput writes a separate file and only if the the write is successful does it unlink the old file and execute a rename -- this means that if something goes wrong during the writes that you data doesn't get clobbered.

Comment: gotcha. Also is it possible to do data = f.read() data= data.replace() f.write(data) instead of reading line by line?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to open a file for both reading and writing using mode "r+"

```
data = []
with open("temp", "r+") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        ar = line.split(",")
        if ar[0] in ("Town 2", "Town 4"):
            data.append( (ar[0], int(ar[1]) - 20, "\n") )
        else:
            data.append(ar)

    inFile.seek(0)
    for d in data:
        inFile.write(",".join([str(x) for x in d]))
    inFile.truncate()
```

In order to keep everything clean, I rewind the file after reading it using seek(0), write every line back into it from a buffer, and truncate any remaining part of the file before closing it. I would be interested to know if and when these operations aren't necessary.

This variation doesn't modify (clobber) any other files in the directory, which is a benefit in cases where the code might run simultaneously on different input files. I have no idea if only opening one file one time has any performance benefit, but it probably does to a small degree.

Comment: I don't know about performance, but this answer is great in my opinion. It preserves the file's encoding, and you can use newline='' and infile.newlines to preserve the original line endings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. Just be sure to save infile.newlines before infile.seek(0), which, oddly, in my opinion, removes newlines from infile.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mod_lines = []

with open("Potatoes.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        info = line.split(",")
        if info[0] in ("Town 2", "Town 4"):
            info[1] = int(info[1]) - 20
        mod_lines.append(info)

with open("Potatoes.txt", "w") as f:
    for m in mod_lines:
        f.write(",".join([str(x) for x in m]))
```

This is certainly not the best way, but it's certainly better and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module to do the file/string handling.

Just read all the values in and loop over them line by line, making adjustments as required. Then write them back to a new file using a `csv.writer` object.

```
import csv
import shutil
import os

with open('potatoes.txt') as f, open('newpotatoes.txt', 'w') as fout:
    rdr = csv.reader(f)
    wrt = csv.writer(fout)

    for line in rdr:
        if line[0] in ('Town 2', 'Town 4'):
            line[1] = str(int(line[1]) - 20)
        wrt.writerow(line)

shutil.copyfile('newpotatoes.txt', 'potatoes.txt')
os.remove('newpotatoes.txt')
```

The line

```
line[1] = str(int(line[1]) - 20)
```

is possibly a little messy. It arises because the values from the csv are all strings. So this is a simple way to convert it to an integer, subtract 20 and convert back to a string.

Looking at your code, there is a mistake in there often made by beginners.

```
if "Town 2" or "Town 4" in line:
```

You have to realize that this is combination of two separate statements and is not what you expect. The first statement is just `Town 2`, which will always evaluate to `True`. The second statement is `"Town 4" in line"`, which will return True if the string "Town 4" is contained anywhere in the `line` string.

Your intent was no doubt to test if either string was in `line`. To do that you need to explicitly test both strings.

```
if "Town 2" in line or "Town 4" in line:
```

Will work as expected. You can take it a step further though and cut out some inelegance present in that statement.

You know that string should always occur in the first element of the string, after the `split` this is `info[0]` in your code (or `line[0]` in mine as I let `csv` do the split).

You can therefore write

```
if line[0] in ('Town 2', 'Town 4'):
```

Which I think you'll agree is easier to read and less repetitive typing, especially if you go on to add more Towns.